# Single keypress firing twice when controlling content in a second window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The problem: I'm getting double keypresses from one keypress event when that event updates content in two windows. (I am a hobbyist. Please forgive my lack of expertise. Thanks.)

I am trying to use one browser window to control the display of contents in a window launched from that first window. That first window also has a div that shows the content sent to the second window.

I'm using shortcut.js to assign to the space bar the command to update each window. But the problem I'm about to describe also occurs when I use the plain old jQuery keypress() function. I've tried altering the parameters of the shortcut.js function to no avail.

Here's a simplified version of the code:

```
g_win = window.open('displaywin.html'); // launch the second window
slideContent = updateTheContent(); // get new content for window #2
slideContentPreview = alterTheContent(slideContent); // modify it for window #1

if (g_win != undefined){ // Is window #2 open?
    $("#display2").html(slideContent);  // display the content in window #2
}
$("#display1").html(slideContentPreview); // always display the content in window #1
```

Here's the jquery keypress code:

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
switch(e.which) {
    case 32: {  // space
        showNextSlide();
        break;
    }
default: return; 
}
e.preventDefault();
});
```

The weird thing is that it works fine if I haven't launched the second window. But if g_win is launched, the content is updated properly, but the Space keypress event is triggered again, causing the program to update the contents again. The effect is that every other piece of content is skipped in both windows.

What amazingly obvious mistake am I making? Thanks!

[LATER:] Here is the entire html for window #2:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>whatev</title>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Special+Elite' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Serif' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <!--link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/displaywin.css"-->
   </head>
    <body>

    <div id="container">
   <div id="display2">
        Click in presenter view to start
    </div>

    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: More code will be helpful to sort out the issue .

Comment: If windows 1 and 2 are open then only acknowledge the keypress from window 2. If only 1 window is open then acknowledge keypress from window 1. I'm not sure what the syntax would be for this off the top of my head so I'll try it in jsfiddle and get back to you. But I think this is what would need to be done.

Comment: Siddharth, I'd be happy (well, except for the embarrassment) to provide more code, but the whole script is 600 lines, and I'm not sure which are the relevant parts. Hobbyist! Not very good hobbyist!

Comment: Thanks, racecarjonathan. I appreciate your going to the trouble of jsfiddling.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you bind the same keypress event handler a second time when you load the second window, because it loads the same javascript. You might solve this issue by only setting the handler when window 2 is not yet loaded. Something along the lines of:

```
if($("#display2").html() == ""){
  $(document).keypress(function(e) {
  switch(e.which) {
    case 32: {  // space
        showNextSlide();
        break;
    }
  default: return; 
  }
  e.preventDefault();
  });
}
```

Comment: Alas, your suggestion didn't work. The keypress binding code runs on the loading of window #1, but not when window #2 is created. Window #2 has no code in it; it is purely for html display. So #2's header only has include statements for some Google fonts, and a css file that I've commented out. Nevertheless, I tried your code with (g_win != undefined) as the condition. Same problem :(